# Calculate how many binary numbers with X number of 1 bits exist between two given binary numbers with the same property

Tags: java, binary, combinatorics

This has been a challenge for me for some time.

Given two arrays that represent binary numbers, A and C with the same size, consisting of bits represented by the numbers 0 or 1, such that C > A, and both have the same X number of 1 bits, what is the most efficient way to calculate how many binaries B exist, such that A   < B < C, and that every B also has X number of 1 bits?.

Example: For A={0,1,0,0,1} C={1,0,1,0,0} X=2
All B's would be {0,1,0,1,0},{0,1,1,0,0},{1,0,0,0,1},{1,0,0,1,0}, which would give me the answer 4. There are 4 binaries with 2 '1' bits between 01001 and 10100.

I have an algorithm to generate the next B given some A, but i feel that it wouldnt be efficient to keep generating the next B AND checking if i have hit the C binary yet.

Is there any way to calculate the exact number of B's between A and C without generating the B's?

Comment: Why are you worried about the efficiency of your algorithm? Unless you are going to be calculating this for numbers with millions of bit, or calculating it millions of times, go for elegance and clarity and ignore efficiency. Iterating from A to C counting the numbers with N 1 bits seems like the most straightforward solution and likely to be plenty efficient enough.

Comment: `Integer#bitCount` is an O(1) operation; I wouldn't worry about efficiency if I were you in this case.

Comment: where is your algorithm?

Comment: One of the reasons, I admit, is for curiosity. I just want to know if there is a 'formula', or something. The other reason, more important, is that for any additional cell to the arrays, the number of total binaries is multiplied by 2, so if i have A[50] and C[50], the number of times i would have to use the algorithm to generate the B's could go to the millions,billions etc.

Comment: With a relatively fast PC, a brute force algorithm would still finish in a second or two.

Comment: I wouldnt need to check if the number i generated has X bits because the algorithm i have does that, it generates the next binary with X bits. The worry i have is that i would always have to compare B to C to check if i have reached it yet. Since they are arrays i dont believe it would be as fast as just if(b==c){stop;}

Comment: Honestly there most likely exists a combinatoric formula that you can use; I'd post on http://math.stackexchange.com/ if I were you.  If you get an algorithm there, I can write you up a program for it.

Comment: I'll do that right now, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if you've got an answer on https://math.stackexchange.com/, but let me take a stab at it.

In all the discussions below, we're only interested in numbers with `X` 1-bits. I'm not gonna keep saying that, to keep it simpler.

So, let's assume we can calculate the count of numbers below a given value `A`: `smaller(A)`. To find the count of numbers between `A` and `C`, we can calculate that as `smaller(C) - smaller(A) - 1`.

Let's define a function that counts how many numbers with X bits exists in a Y-bit space, `count(X, Y)`, e.g. `count(1, 3) = 3` (`001`, `010`, `100`) and `count(2, 3) = 3` (`011`, `101`, `110`). This is standard combination math, i.e. number of combinations to pull X balls numbered 1 to Y from a bag.

```
count(X, Y) = Y! / ((Y-X)! * X!)
```

where `X!` is `factorial(X)`.

Now I'm going to show the next part, how to calculate `smaller(A)`, using an example. Let `A = 010010100`.

First, count the 0's on the right (2). There are then `count(1, 2)` numbers below `A` where the right-most 1-bit is moved to the right (`010010010`, `010010001`).

*Hint: Use [`count = Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(A)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#numberOfTrailingZeros-int-)*

Remove that 1-bit, leaving `A = 010010000`.

*Hint: Use `A = A ^ (1 << count)`*

Repeat, i.e. count 0's (4), but this time we need count of 2-bits combinations, i.e. `count(2, 4)`.

That leaves `A = 010000000`, which leads to `count(3, 7)`.

So, because the 1-bits were at bit 2, 4, and 7, we can calculate:

```
smaller(A) = count(1, 2) + count(2, 4) + count(3, 7)
```

Now, with a good efficient implementation of `count(X, Y)`, it shouldn't be too bad to calculate count of numbers between A and C, even for high bit-counts.

Anyway, that's one way to do it, but the geniuses over on the math side may have better algorithms for this.

Comment: This is actually the exact same algorithm a guy in math se told me, but this is more programmer-friendly haha. Amazing! Thank you so much for taking the time to explain! Link to the other person's answer http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2230248/calculating-number-of-binaries-with-x-number-of-1-digits-given-a-range?noredirect=1#comment4585936_2230248